# In the modular exponentiation, as used with the adaptive root problem, how to chose the best base that will yield as few results as possible?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, analytic-number-theory, approximation-algorithms, probabilistic-number-theory

Let $n,m,w\in\Bbb N$ and $\lambda\in\Bbb P$ such that $w^\lambda \mod m = n$, with the requirements:

- $\lambda$ being a random large prime such as $w^\lambda > 2\times m$
- $1 < n < m−1$.
- m is a large semiprime hard to factor.

In order to have the highest chance of success, which base $w$ to choose, for a given modulus $m$ to minimize the number of possible $n$ ?

For example, if we have $w^{\text{random $\lambda$}}\!\! \mod 13$, and we chose $w=10$ then, the possible $n$ values will be $9$ $12$ $3$ $4$ $1$ $10$ in that order. But if we chose $w=97$ then the possible reminder $n$ values will be $5$ $4$ $11$ $1$ $6$ $10$ $8$ $9$ $2$ $12$ $7$ $3$ therefore, choosing $w=10$ is a better candidate than $w=97$ because there’s a higher chance that the selected $n$ will be the right answer for the given random λ when $m=13$.

Now if the modulus $m$ is 71012135994133966684654355937062538968244152586650979104299906106437025595499, how to efficiently compute the value $w$ that’ll yield the smallest number of possible results for such $m$ and with the restrictions above?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is random, then how can you know the order of the possible $n$ values? It seems to me you are simply listing $10^n\bmod{13}$ for $n=2,3,4,5,6,7$ (and it's not clear to me why you start at $n=2$, rather than $n=1$ or $n=0$). If that's all you are doing, you can get fewer values of $n$ with $w=5$, even fewer with $w=12$, still fewer with $w=1$. Given $m$, it looks like you want $w$ of small order modulo $m$. Aside from the obvious choices $w=m-1$ and $w=m$, you have to know something about the factorization of $m-1$ to get anywhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the underlying problem is used in cryptography for a verifiable random function. With n=1 or n=m−1. The answer would be too easy which in turns bans $w=1$ and w=m−1 which is why I added the requirement in my question. Why would knowing the factors of $m−1$ would help? Are you sure you don t want to mean $m$ which is a prime (and thus impossible to factor)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson for the possible values of 10<sup>λ</sup>, it s a bit like when you divide by something. A number sequence will always repeat and do does the possible remainders.

Comment: I mean $m-1$. The residue classes $\{1,2,3,\dotsc,m-1\}$ form a cyclic group of order $m-1$ under the operation of multiplication modulo $m$, if $m$ is prime, so that group has a subgroup of order $d$ precisely when $d$ is a factor of $m-1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know I didn t wrote my question like this, but if m is a semi prime, then this won t work? (Hence factoring m but which is impossible if m is 2048 bits long). Otherwise, it s correct I m attempting to find a working pair of $n$ and $w$.

Comment: Make up your mind; is $m$ a prime, or a product of two primes?

Comment: @GerryMyerson in reality it can be both.

Comment: Well, if it's a prime, then what I wrote, applies.

Comment: @GerryMyerson and if not, it doesn’t ?

Comment: As you are interested in this, I'd suggest you grab an intro Number Theory textbook and read up on it. Pretty much any such text will cover this material, and I'm not keen on duplicating them here. But: if $m=pq$, with $p$ and $q$ distinct odd primes, then the residues that are relatively prime to $m$ still form a group under multiplication modulo $m$, but it is no longer a cyclic group. It has order $\phi(m)=(p-1)(q-1)$, and is the direct sum of the cyclic groups of orders $p-1$ and $q-1$. Every element has order dividing the least common multiple of $p-1$ and $q-1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes I know it, but if m is 1024 bits long, the answer is you can t find p q. Hence, asking `is factoring m-1 usefull if m is a semiprime?` again because factoring m-1 is likely to be simpler.

Comment: The order of a subgroup divides the order of the group. That's why factoring $m-1$ is useful if $m$ is prime, and that's why factoring $(p-1)(q-1)$ is useful if $m$ is the product of the distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Think that through, and you should be able to answer the question you have just asked.

Comment: @GerryMyerson in that case, question edited.

Comment: Well, you edited "large semiprime" into the question, but you still illustrate it with $m=13$. Anyway, my advice about reading up on these questions still stands. I'll just add that the reason people use large semiprimes in, say, RSA is that there are computationally infeasible questions concerning them, so maybe what you want to do, can't be done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the illustration still stands with semiprimes. the underlying problem is the adaptive root problem derived from rsa. But it s not rsa.

Comment: If you could factor large semiprimes, then you could solve your problem, right? And if you could factor large semiprimes, you could break RSA, right? So, your problem isn't RSA, but it's just as hard as breaking RSA, and for the same reason that breaking RSA is hard: it's hard to factor large semiprimes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It s currently unproven factoring is the only way to solve that kind of subproblem. Hence partly why it s on Mathoverflow. As a student, I might completely be wrong, but it seems limiting the number of possible results is a good step even if still too large. Problem is finding which bases allows to do it.